# Jquery attribute equals selector only selects the first element

Tags: php, jquery

My equals selector is only selecting the first item on my list.
It doesn't matter which image I click, it always sets my jQuery variables to the first item.
Thanks!

```
//PHP

<div class="imgContain">
<img id="finalimg" alt="first" src="website.com/imga546.jpg">
<img id="finalimg" alt="second" src="website.com/imga645.jpg">
<img id="finalimg" alt="thrid" src="website.com/imga6786.jpg">
<img id="finalimg" alt="4th" src="website.com/imga31234.jpg">
</div>


//jQuery   
$('.imgContain').on("click", "img", function () {
         var srcc = $('img[id="finalimg"]').attr('src');
         var linkU = $('img[id="finalimg"]').attr('alt'); 

       });
```

Comment: What output u want when i click on imgContain div?

Answer (score 1):

Since `id` must be unique, you need to use class instead:

```
<div class="imgContain">
    <img class="finalimg" alt="first" src="website.com/imga546.jpg">
    <img class="finalimg" alt="second" src="website.com/imga645.jpg">
    <img class="finalimg" alt="thrid" src="website.com/imga6786.jpg">
    <img class="finalimg" alt="4th" src="website.com/imga31234.jpg">
</div>
```

then you can use `.` to target elements by class as well as using `$(this)` to get reference to current clicked image with class `finalimg`:

```
$('.imgContain').on("click", ".finalimg", function () {
    var srcc = $(this).attr('src');
    var linkU = $(this).attr('alt'); 
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VUxG5/)**

Comment: ID needn't be unique. I think jQuery handles it properly. Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/txvv2/1/

Comment: No, `id` must be unique: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454645/does-id-have-to-be-unique-in-the-whole-page. Your code work because you're applying `$(this)`.

Answer (score 0):

You get Unique ID of image on its click and do manipulation as follows
Working fiddle demo http://fiddle.jshell.net/8kmdt/

```
<div class="imgContain">
<img id="img1" alt="first" src="website.com/imga546.jpg">
<img id="img2" alt="second" src="website.com/imga645.jpg">
<img id="img3" alt="thrid" src="website.com/imga6786.jpg">
<img id="img4" alt="4th" src="website.com/imga31234.jpg">
</div>
then change your jQuery code to:

$('.imgContain').on("click", "img", function () {
var getID=$(this).attr("id");
  var source = $("#"+getID).attr('src');
  var linkOfImg = $("#"+getID).attr('alt'); 
});
```

Comment: Why not use `$(this).attr('src')` directly?

Comment: You mean $(this).attr("src") ?

Comment: Its possible , But in complex scenarios , without using ID everything will  become messed up and complex.Its good practice while using jQuery.

Answer (score -1):

element id's need to be unique. you should use classes instead.

Comment: ID needn't be unique. I think jQuery handles it properly. http://jsfiddle.net/txvv2/1/

Comment: regardless, its bad form to have multiple elements with the same id. In fact, [W3 says that an ID "must be unique in a document"](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2)